# Query from multiple tables where not always the PMK exist in all the tables

Tags: mysql

My current query is:

```
select 
    item_description.fk_i_item_id, item_description.s_title, item_description.s_description, 
    category_description.s_slug, 
    item_resource.s_path, item_resource.s_extension, item_resource.pk_i_id
FROM
    item, item_description, category_description, item_resource
 
WHERE
    item.pk_i_id = item_description.fk_i_item_id
AND
    category_description.fk_i_category_id = 96
AND 
    item.pk_i_id = item_resource.fk_i_item_id 

GROUP BY item.pk_i_id
ORDER BY item.pk_i_id DESC
```

Basically these tables store some item's info (with optional info stored in **item_resource**), I'm trying to get all the useful info from all these 4 tables, it works good when the item has *resource* (the optional info in **item_resource**), but if the item doesn't have resource, then the item will not appear on the result.

So I need a result where the item is returned too no matter if it has info on the item_resource table or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I need a result where the item is returned too no matter if it has
>   info on the item_resource table or not.

Then consider doing a `OUTER JOIN` and most probably a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of doing a `INNER JOIN`. What you are currently performing is an inner join and that to a old style join syntax when you say `FROM item, item_description, category_description, item_resource`. You should consider using ANSI style `JOIN` syntax rather.

Also, don't see any need of that `GROUP BY item.pk_i_id` since you are not performing any aggregation.

I mean something like below:

```
select 
    item_description.fk_i_item_id, item_description.s_title, 
    item_description.s_description, 
    category_description.s_slug, 
    item_resource.s_path, item_resource.s_extension, item_resource.pk_i_id
FROM
    item
LEFT JOIN item_description ON item.pk_i_id = item_description.fk_i_item_id
LEFT JOIN category_description ON category_description.some_column = item.pk_i_id
AND category_description.fk_i_category_id = 96
LEFT JOIN item_resource ON item.pk_i_id = item_resource.fk_i_item_id
ORDER BY item.pk_i_id DESC;
```

Comment: The "GROUP BY item.pk_i_id" is needed because sometimes there are more than on resource, so in that case the entry is duplicated. adding the GROUP BY worked like a charm. THANK YOU